# BillingClient не пойму что происходит

Tags: java, android

Суть вопроса как сделать чтобы программа не пересоздавала окно ?

Помогите разобраться

- ситуация следующего характера :

Вот часть кода в котором проверяется купленный контент пользователя .

Сразу грузится  Main0Activity  после проверки грузиться  MainActivity.class (соответственно и его activity)

Все работает должным образом !

Но стоит свернуть программу и параллельно открыть Google Play после этого закрыть его из диспетчера  происходит следующее : вызывается метод  Vibro() и Intent_MainActivity(); с вязи с этим  пересоздается окно программы хотя программу даже не трогали .

Вот логи в момент закрытия гугл плей (перед тем как пересоздается окно )

```
2020-11-04 20:41:29.035 28987-28987/ W/BillingClient: Billing service disconnected.
2020-11-04 20:41:31.086 28987-28987/ W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@d89477a
```

Судя из логов понятно , что  Billing service disconnected но как это может перезагружать activity.

И это происходит только с гугл плей .

P.s (Обновлял библиотеки на самые новые безрезультатно )

///

```
 public class Main0Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Vibrator Vibro;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Home_AppTheme);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main0);


            Toast.makeText(Main0Activity.this,(R.string.internet_activity),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mBillingClient();

    }


    private Map<String, SkuDetails> mSkuDetailsMap = new HashMap<>();

    private String load = "1_1_1";

    private BillingClient mBillingClient;

    public void mBillingClient() {
        mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {}
        }).build();


        mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {
                if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                    //здесь мы можем запросить информацию о товарах и покупках
                    querySkuDetails();
                    List<Purchase> purchasesList = queryPurchases();
                    for (int i = 0; i < purchasesList.size(); i++) {
                        String purchaseId = purchasesList.get(i).getSku();

                        if(TextUtils.equals(load, purchaseId)) {
                            payComplete1();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                //сюда мы попадем если что-то пойдет не так
            }
        });
    }
    

    private void querySkuDetails() {
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder skuDetailsParamsBuilder = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();

        skuList.add(load);


        skuDetailsParamsBuilder.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(skuDetailsParamsBuilder.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
                if (responseCode == 0) {
                    for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        mSkuDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getSku(), skuDetails);
                    }
                }

                Vibro();

                finish();
                Intent_MainActivity();

            }
        });
    }


    public void payComplete1()
    {}
    

    private List<Purchase> queryPurchases() {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
        return purchasesResult.getPurchasesList();
    }
    
    //////////////


    public void  Vibro ()
    {
        Vibro = (Vibrator)this.getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        Vibro.vibrate(50);
        
    }

    public void Intent_MainActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В жизненном цикле !

mBillingClient.endConnection();